# Use Boost Rtree with geographic coordinates

Tags: c++, rtree, boost.geometry

In order to find nearest nodes I'm using boost  rtree as follows:

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2,  boost::geometry::cs::geographic<boost::geometry::degree>> RtreePoint;
typedef boost::geometry::model::box<RtreePoint> RtreeBox;
typedef std::pair<RtreePoint, node_id_t> RtreePointValue;
typedef boost::geometry::index::rtree<RtreePointValue, boost::geometry::index::rstar<16>> Rtree;

// building tree
for(const auto& node: nodes) {
  rtree.insert(std::make_pair(RtreePoint { node.latitude, node.longitude }, node.id));
}

// then search for nearest neighbours for particular node
std::vector<RtreePointValue> closest;
const auto& query = boost::geometry::index::nearest(RtreePoint { node.latitude, node.longitude }, limit);
std::copy(rtree.qbegin(query), rtree.qend(), std::back_inserter(closest));
```

At first glance it seems to work but nodes are not sorted exactly by distance to the `node`. Can it be improved? In general can I use boost Rtree for geographic coordinates? If not, what can I use instead?

Boost version is 1.72.

Note: I eventually resolved it by converting nodes to cartesian coordinates.